# Python multiple inheritance: picking which base class' method to call

Tags: python, postgresql, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, amazon-redshift

I have defined a class `C` that inherits from `A`. Now there's a new class `B` that provides the same methods as `A` but has a slightly different behaviour.

How can I design class `C` such that it's easy to use `A` or `B` as the base class? Ideally I'd like to make this change with as little work as possible for now, even if it's a bit ugly to use.

For additional context on the problem, `A` and `B` are [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) cursors. `A` is a standard cursor, while `B` is a dictcursor. `C` is a wrapper around the cursor that provides Redshift-specific functionality.

Comment: why don't you pass an object of type either A or B as an argument to the constructor of C, where C can call methods on this object?

Comment: I also want to be able to call methods of `A` directly on objects of type `C`, e.g. I want to be able to call `c.execute()` where `execute` is defined on `A` and `B`. If I can't achieve this all, I might have to go your way, but it's sub-optimal as it'll make the code using the class less clean.

Comment: you can implement [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) on class C so that it will fall back on the inner object.

Comment: Ooh! That could work quite well. Let me have a look and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You use the [super](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) function like so:

```
class A(object):
    def foo(self, arg):
        print arg, 'in parent class'

class C(A):
    def foo(self, arg):
        super(C, self).foo(arg)
        print arg, 'in subclass'

>>> C().foo('bar')
bar in parent class
bar in subclass
```

If you do this, C's methods don't ever have to know about their base implementations.